# Pause loading html elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Dream weaver js code (not mine) from 2004 year. It should type symbols with some delay. But it doesn't.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  // alert() // if I put an alert, everyting works correct
  theDate=new Date();
  thetime=Date().toString();
  curtime=new Date();
  lasttime=new Date();
  var val=1000;
  var newval=0;
 function delay(val) {
   var t3=0; 
   lasttime=new Date()
    t1=lasttime.getTime();
    t3=t1+val;
     curtime=new Date();
    t2=curtime.getTime();
    while (t2 < t3) {
       curtime=new Date();
       t2=curtime.getTime();
    }
}
 document.wait=delay;
<!--->
</script><script>
val=parseInt(top.frames[0].myform.mytext.value);
document.wait(val);
</script><script>
document.wait(val);
</script><script>
document.wait(val);
</script><script>
//val=100;
document.wait(val);
</script>
<B><BASEFONT SIZE="6" FACE="Arial Cyr" COLOR="#8000FF">&nbsp;
 # &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<script> document.wait(val);</script>&nbsp;
, &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<script> document.wait(val);</script> &quot;<script> document.wait(val);</script>
 &amp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<script> document.wait(val);</script>
  § &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<script> document.wait(val);</script>
```

But if I put alert before this code (it is commented in the sample) it will work. Not in all browsers (it will not work in IE, for example), but it will. How can I fix it without alert and why alert makes code work right?

Answer (score 1):

As Yogi suggested, you should use a timeout or `async` functions to render characters to an element.

```js
const typeWriter = (elementOrSelector, text, speed = 10) => {
  const el = typeof elementOrSelector === 'string'
    ? document.querySelector(elementOrSelector)
    : elementOrSelector;
  let i = 0;
  const fn = () => {
    if (i < text.length) {
      el.textContent += text[i++];
      setTimeout(fn, speed);
    }
  }
  fn();
};

typeWriter('#demo-slow', 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.', 100);
typeWriter('#demo-fast', 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.', 50);
typeWriter('#demo-faster', 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.', 25);
```

```css
p { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<p id="demo-slow"></p>
<p id="demo-fast"></p>
<p id="demo-faster"></p>
```

Here is an `async` version with a sleep:

```js
const sleep = async (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

const typeWriterAsync = async (elementOrSelector, text, speed = 10) => {
  const el = typeof elementOrSelector === 'string'
    ? document.querySelector(elementOrSelector)
    : elementOrSelector;
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    await sleep(speed);
    el.textContent += text[i];
  }
};

// All at once, like above
typeWriterAsync('#demo-slow', 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.', 100);
typeWriterAsync('#demo-fast', 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.', 50);
typeWriterAsync('#demo-faster', 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.', 25);

// You can also chain
(async() => {
  await typeWriterAsync('#demo-slow-chain', 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.', 100);
  await typeWriterAsync('#demo-fast-chain', 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.', 50);
  await typeWriterAsync('#demo-faster-chain', 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.', 25);
  console.log('Done!');
})();
```

```css
p { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<p id="demo-slow"></p>
<p id="demo-fast"></p>
<p id="demo-faster"></p>
<hr />
<p id="demo-slow-chain"></p>
<p id="demo-fast-chain"></p>
<p id="demo-faster-chain"></p>
```

Comment: But my aim is to make old code working. And also I want to understand why alert is fixing the situation

Comment: @ОлегО The old code is not worth salvaging as Yogi stated. Take the original intended business logic and modernize it from the ground-up. Browser JavaScript is an entirely different beast than what it was back in 2004.